# SQL Combining Rows With Multiple Distinct Values

Tags: sql, view, distinct, rows

Hey all so I have created a view using some tables in my DB.

My view looks like..
[image]
Listing all Order information.

Next, I need to make another view based on the one shown above. For this one I need to display only the Product Names, Total number of times product has been ordered, and the Total price for that product.

I am having trouble combining the ProductNames whilst also combining the Quantity and ItemTotal.

I have tried using Distinct(ProductName)

```
CREATE VIEW ProductSummary AS
SELECT DISTINCT(ProductName), Quantity AS OrderCount, ItemTotal
FROM OrderItemProducts
```

however that just results in..

[image]

Which is not correct because it displays duplicate ProductNames 
(because they have different OrderCounts).

I would like to Combine the Duplicate rows and total the OrderCount and ItemTotals. What is the best and/or most correct way to do this?

Comment: `group by` is what you need.  `SELECT ProductName, Sum(Quantity) AS OrderCount, Sum(ItemTotal)
FROM OrderItemProducts Group by ProductName`  Or something of that nature.

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` and `sum`:

```
CREATE VIEW ProductSummary AS
SELECT ProductName, sum(Quantity) AS OrderCount, sum(ItemTotal) as ItemTotal
FROM OrderItemProducts 
Group by ProductName
```